# Magento 2 Interceptor generation error: during running di:compile command

Tags: magento2, module, controllers

Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write.

I also want to save the form data custom db table named "prescription_form"

My Controller code is:

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{       
    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_postFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Softadroit\Prescription\Controller\Index $postFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        
        
        if (!empty($post)) {
            $name   = $post['name'];
            $age    = $post['age'];
            $weight = $post['weight'];
            $height = $post['height'];
            $gender = $post['gender'];
            $product_id = $post['product_id'];
            $customer_id = $post['customer_id'];
        
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\Prescription');           
            /* $model->setName($name);
            $model->setAge($age);
            $model->setWeight($weight);
            $model->setHeight($height);
            $model->setGender($gender);
            $model->setGender($product_id);
            $model->setGender($customer_id); */
            $model->setData([
                    "name" => $name,
                    "age" => $age,
                    "weight" => $weight,
                    "height" => $height,
                    "gender" => $gender,
                    "product_id" => $product_id,
                    "customer_id" => $customer_id
                    ]);
        
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($model);
        die(); */
            
             $msg ="";
             $data =  $model->save();
            if($data != ''){ 
                //$model->save(); 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Thanks your form is submitted successfully!');
            }else{ 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Error in submitting data. Please contact on this email!'); 
            } 
            echo $msg; 
            
            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/prescription/index');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
       
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Resource model code:

```
<?php
namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Model\ResourceModel;


class Prescription extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('prescription_form', 'id');
    }
    
}
```

Model code:

```
<?php
namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Model;
class Prescription extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'prescription_form';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'prescription_form';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'prescription_form';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\ResourceModel\Prescription');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

HTML template code I used to make form:

```
<?php
// Get all visible items in cart
$quote = $block->getQuoteData();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form name="addData" method="post" id="addData" class="form" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <?php foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) { 
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
            $customerId = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();
            //echo $product->getPrescription(); //die();
            $is_priscription = $product->getData('prescription');
            if($is_priscription != "" && $is_priscription == '5431'){  // change prescription option id here ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend"><span>Add Prescription: <?php echo $_item->getName(); ?></span></legend>
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                    <div class="fields col-md-6">
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="name"><span>Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="name[]" id="name" title="Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="age"><span>Age</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="age[]" id="Age" title="Age" class="input-text" type="int" data-validate="{required:true}"> Years</input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="height"><span>Height</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="height[]" id="Height" title="Height" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"> FT</input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="weight"><span>Weight</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="weight[]" id="Weight" title="Weight" class="input-text" type="int" data-validate="{required:true}"> KG</input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="gender"><span>Gender</span></label>
                            <select name="subject_gender[]">
                            <option>---Select Gender--</option>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>                      
                        <!--<div class="field date required">
                            <label class="label" for="publish_date"><span>Publish Date</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="publish_date" id="datepicker"  data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="display:none">             
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="product_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="product_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>"><?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="customer_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="product_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $_item->getCustomerId(); ?>"><?php echo $customerId; ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <?php } } ?>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="Save"><span>Save</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
    $("#datepicker").calendar({
        showsTime: false,
        dateFormat: "M/d/Y",
        yearRange: "-120y:c+nn",
        maxDate: "-1d", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true})
    });
</script>
```

I attached an image while I am running the di:compile command.I have some errors there.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step: 1**

Please change the code in controller file as below

**From:**

```
protected $_postFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Softadroit\Prescription\Controller\Index $postFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

**To:**

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

After that run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
And then you can run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

**Step 2:**

Change the code in controller section

**From =**

```
if (!empty($post)) {
            $name   = $post['name'];
            $age    = $post['age'];
            $weight = $post['weight'];
            $height = $post['height'];
            $gender = $post['gender'];
            $product_id = $post['product_id'];
            $customer_id = $post['customer_id'];
        
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\Prescription');           
            /* $model->setName($name);
            $model->setAge($age);
            $model->setWeight($weight);
            $model->setHeight($height);
            $model->setGender($gender);
            $model->setGender($product_id);
            $model->setGender($customer_id); */
            $model->setData([
                    "name" => $name,
                    "age" => $age,
                    "weight" => $weight,
                    "height" => $height,
                    "gender" => $gender,
                    "product_id" => $product_id,
                    "customer_id" => $customer_id
                    ]);
        
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($model);
        die(); */
            
             $msg ="";
             $data =  $model->save();
            if($data != ''){ 
                //$model->save(); 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Thanks your form is submitted successfully!');
            }else{ 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Error in submitting data. Please contact on this email!'); 
            } 
            echo $msg; 
            
            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/prescription/index');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
```

**To=**

```
if (!empty($post)) {
   foreach($post['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $age    = $post['age'][$key];
            $weight = $post['weight'][$key];
            $height = $post['height'][$key];
            $gender = $post['gender'][$key];
            $product_id = $post['product_id'][$key];
            $customer_id = $post['customer_id'][$key];
        
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\Prescription');           
            
            $model->setData([
                    "name" => $name,
                    "age" => $age,
                    "weight" => $weight,
                    "height" => $height,
                    "gender" => $gender,
                    "product_id" => $product_id,
                    "customer_id" => $customer_id
                    ]);

             $msg ="";
             $data =  $model->save();
            if($data != ''){ 
                //$model->save(); 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Thanks your form is submitted successfully!');
            }else{ 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Error in submitting data. Please contact on this email!'); 
            } 
}
            echo $msg; 

            $cartObject = $this->cartFactory->create()->truncate();
            $cartObject->saveQuote();
            
            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/prescription/index');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
```

Comment: I found this error while submitting form **Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion **

Comment: Data is echo in array but not get stored in db. Please have a look on the code

Comment: every attribute as an array. like $post['name'] is an array so you have to use foreach for every data.

Comment: I want to clear quote after submitting this form so what I have to do?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the above answer. Please try.

Comment: Thankyou for this is working fine for me

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320774/magento-how-to-redirect-to-a-phtml-page-from-a-controller Can you please help me in this