# Magento: How to redirect to a phtml page from a controller?

Tags: magento2, redirect

I have a controller and from there I want to redirect to a custom phtml file.

My controller path is app/code/Softadroit/Prescription/Controller/index/Save.php

The phtml file is stored in app/code/Softadroit/Prescription/view/frontend/templates/Success.phtml

How can I redirect to this page from my controller?

This is my controller code but it is not redirecting to that phtml file:

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{    
    protected $_pageFactory;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($post);
        die(); */
        
        if (!empty($post)) {
        foreach($post['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $age    = $post['age'][$key];
            $weight = $post['weight'][$key];
            $height = $post['height'][$key];
            $gender = $post['subject_gender'][$key];
            $product_id = $post['product_id'][$key];
            $customer_id = $post['customer_id'][$key];
        
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\Prescription');           
            
            $model->setData([
                    "name" => $name,
                    "age" => $age,
                    "weight" => $weight,
                    "height" => $height,
                    "gender" => $gender,
                    "product_id" => $product_id,
                    "customer_id" => $customer_id
                    ]);

             $msg ="";
             $data =  $model->save();
            if($data != ''){ 
                //$model->save(); 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Thanks your form is submitted successfully!');
            }else{ 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Error in submitting data. Please contact on this email!'); 
            } 
}
            echo $msg; 

            $cartObject = $this->cartFactory->create()->truncate();
            $cartObject->saveQuote();
            
            
            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/prescription/index/success');
            //$resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/onepage/successs');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
       
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create files as below:

Softadroit/Prescription/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="prescription" frontName="prescription">
            <module name="Softadroit_Prescription" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Softadroit/Prescription/view/layout/prescription_index_save.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.save" template="Softadroit_Prescription::Success.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Change in controller as below

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{    
    protected $_pageFactory;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($post);
        die(); */
        
        if (!empty($post)) {
        foreach($post['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $age    = $post['age'][$key];
            $weight = $post['weight'][$key];
            $height = $post['height'][$key];
            $gender = $post['subject_gender'][$key];
            $product_id = $post['product_id'][$key];
            $customer_id = $post['customer_id'][$key];
        
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\Prescription');           
            
            $model->setData([
                    "name" => $name,
                    "age" => $age,
                    "weight" => $weight,
                    "height" => $height,
                    "gender" => $gender,
                    "product_id" => $product_id,
                    "customer_id" => $customer_id
                    ]);

             $msg ="";
             $data =  $model->save();
            if($data != ''){ 
                //$model->save(); 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Thanks your form is submitted successfully!');
            }else{ 
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Error in submitting data. Please contact on this email!'); 
            } 
}
            echo $msg; 

            $cartObject = $this->cartFactory->create()->truncate();
            $cartObject->saveQuote();
            
           
        }
       
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601780/magento-2-how-to-get-quote-product-id-in-an-observer

Answer (score 2):

check the below code

**In controller:**

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Controller\Index;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory          = $pageFactory;
        $this->cartFactory           = $cartFactory;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;

        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($post);
        die(); */

        if (!empty($post)) {
            foreach ($post['name'] as $key => $name) {
                $age         = $post['age'][$key];
                $weight      = $post['weight'][$key];
                $height      = $post['height'][$key];
                $gender      = $post['subject_gender'][$key];
                $product_id  = $post['product_id'][$key];
                $customer_id = $post['customer_id'][$key];

                $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softadroit\Prescription\Model\Prescription');

                $model->setData([
                    "name"        => $name,
                    "age"         => $age,
                    "weight"      => $weight,
                    "height"      => $height,
                    "gender"      => $gender,
                    "product_id"  => $product_id,
                    "customer_id" => $customer_id,
                ]);

                $msg  = "";
                $data = $model->save();
                if ($data != '') {
//$model->save();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Thanks your form is submitted successfully!');
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Error in submitting data. Please contact on this email!');
                }
            }
            echo $msg;

            $cartObject = $this->cartFactory->create()->truncate();
            $cartObject->saveQuote();

        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('prescription/index/success');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code you can please check the question I update my code here have a look, it doesnot redirecting to that phtml file

Comment: You want to call a phtml file from controller or you want to redirect to some page (i.e layout) ?

Comment: After click on button I want the user to redirect to this file Success.phtml

Comment: ok in which layout you have called success.phtml ?

Comment: checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
    <block class="Softadroit\Prescription\Block\Success"
           name="softadroit.order.success"
           template="Softadroit_Prescription::order/success.phtml"
           after="-">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Updated answer please check. also clear var/generated folder or use cmd to di:compile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112284/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-arun-kumar).